# gstreamer rtsp h264 -> udp vp8 memory leak

Tags: video, memory-leaks, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to streaming rtsp stream coming from camera(H264 format).
I am using following gst command to do streaming:

```
gst-launch-0.10 rtspsrc location=rtsp://login:pass@192.168.1.15 latency=0 buffer-mode=0 udp-buffer-size=0 ! rtph264depay ! ffdec_h264 ! timeoverlay halign=right valign=top ! clockoverlay halign=left valign=top time-format='%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' ! vp8enc mode=vbr speed=7 ! rtpvp8pay pt=100 ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=1234
```

There is RAM mermory is gradually increasing.

Does gStreamer has memory leak. or there is problem in my pipeline command?

Comment: Your pipeline looks pretty good, but GStreamer 0.10 is deprecated and you should use the latest in the 1.x if possible and see if you still encounter the issues.

Comment: I tried gst 1.0 and a memory leak disappeared. Thanks ;p

Answer (score 0):

I am using a custom board which is having `AM5728 processor`. I am running `4  Gstreamer pipelines` in the background. The ram of the board is `2GB`, and its consumption is increasing as we keep the board for a longer time and it is killing the pipelines. I also have a `6GB` swap partition in it and that is getting filled over time.

the pipeline which i am using is:

> gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device="/dev/video3" ! 'video/x-raw,format=(string)NV12,width=720,height=240,framerate=(fraction)30/1' ! videoconvert ! queue ! ducatih264enc bitrate=1000 intra-interval=1 ! queue ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay mtu=800 ! queue ! udpsink host=172.196.129.207 port=36000

regards,

Vijay